# what is meaning of Navigator.of(context).pop()?

Tags: flutter

here is my code

```
      preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(60),
      leading: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 9, top: 6, bottom: 6, right: 3),
          child: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back_ios,
            color: kAppColor2,
            size: 18,
```

what is meaning of Navigator.of(context).pop() ?

Answer (score 0):

Use

`Navigator.of(context).pop()`

It pops the current screen out of stack. View [Flutter Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pop.html) regarding this.

Comment: color: _title.isEmpty || _announcement.isEmpty ? Colors.grey : kAppColor2

Whats meaning of this?

Comment: That means that if the _title var is empty or if the _announcement var is empty then your Color is grey, otherwise your color is the constant kAppColor2

Answer (score 0):

Flutter works in a stack form, each new screen you go to gets built, using  Navigator.of(context).pop() returns you to the previous screen on the stack. It's a way to return to the previous screen without the need of adding a new one to the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Navigator constructor creates a widget that maintains a stack-based history of child widgets. `Navigator.of(context).pop()` is used to removed the top-most route off the navigator.

***For example:***

To go to a new screen, use the `Navigator.push()` method. The push() method adds a Route to the stack of routes managed by the Navigator.

Now to return back from that new screen you use the `Navigator.pop()` method. The pop() method removes the current Route from the stack of routes managed by the Navigator.

[Click here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics) to read the official documention from Flutter.